# How does one disable/ re-enable touch events in Android?

Tags: android, touch, android-view

Quick, probably simple, question. I have a view whose background is animating, and during that time, I want to disable the user from interacting with the view. My view is a FrameLayout, and I'm capturing touch events with onTouchEvent(). Solutions I've tried:

1) First setOnTouchListener(null), then setOnTouchListener(this). Problem is, my view only calls onTouchEvent(MotionEvent), and not onTouch(View, MotionEvent), so I can't pump through the Events there.

2) First setEnabled(false), then setEnabled(true). The source code says:  A disabled view that is clickable still consumes the touch events, it just doesn't respond to them. Problem is, MotionEvents still get pumped through in onTouchEvent().

3) requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false), then (true). This only handles touch events from the parent.

The solution I have working is using a boolean variable isAnimating, and checking the value of that in onTouchEvent(). I'd rather not do this, because it looks ugly to me and I'd rather use the API for it than reinvent the wheel, sooo... anyone got any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`setFocusable()` and `setFocusableInTouchMode()`

Comment: I'll try that, thanks.

EDIT: no luck, I can still touch and interact with the view during the animation.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //Check if event is on your view
    if(event.getY()>view.getTop()&&event.getY()<view.getBottom()&&event.getX()>view.getLeft()&&event.getX()<view.getRight()){
        //event occured inside your view

    }
    //here return super or as your logic prefer
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: I think you may be a little confused with my question. I'm wondering if there's a method that will disable onTouchEvent() from being called based on some method the android API gives you, like disallowTouchEvent().

Comment: why dont you just return true inside your conditional statement, which states you have consumed event

Comment: This is what I have inside onTouchEvent(), but I don't prefer it:

if (isAnimating) {
   return true 
}